# Otsu binarization with value preservation

Tags: image-processing, matlab, thresholding

I'm trying to implement a modified version of the otsu binarization algorithm. I'm trying to binarize document images. But in the binarization procedure I want the object (in this case the text) to retain its original grayscale value while the background takes the value of 255; that is, white. I'm posting a sample image version that I found in a paper.

This is the original image:
[image]

This is the resultant image I want to obtain:
[image]

Could someone please tell me how to do it in Matlab?

Comment: You want to retain the giant gray blob?

Comment: i want to retain the original values of all the pixels whose value lies above the threshold. That includes the blob in this case.

Comment: Matlab Source code for Otsu binarization with value preservation..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't have Matlab handy, but here is how you do it in [OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/). The example below uses the python interface via [Python (x, y)](http://code.google.com/p/pythonxy/):

```
test = cv2.imread("test.jpg", 0)
(_, otsu) = cv2.threshold(test, 0.0, 255.0, cv2.THRESH_TOZERO_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
cv2.imshow('otsu', otsu)
```

This results in your required output:
[image]

**EDIT :** I don't have a copy of Matlab, but I think this is how you would do it (assuming you have the Image Processing Toolbox):

Use [graythresh](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/images/ref/graythresh.html) to get the Otsu level, then set anything above that level to white (or 255).

```
I = imread('doc.jpg');
I = rgb2gray(I);
otsuLevel = graythresh(I);
I(I > otsuLevel) = 255;
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: i need the code in matlab. I'm a little new to the software, so need a little help with the coding

Comment: @mark See my edit for a possible Matlab solution.

Answer (score 6):

You can easily do it with Mathematica:

```
img = ColorNegate@ColorConvert[Import["../Desktop/sample.jpg"], "Grayscale"]
ColorNegate@ImageMultiply[Binarize[img], img]
```

The negation and multiplication business is to ensure the preservation of the original grayscale value. You can easily translate this to any language, I think.

[image: Filtered result]